# 502 Error Bad Gateway on EC2 instance (Nginx)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I created my own AWS EC2 instance yesterday, and it was working all fine and dandy. Today I went to use it again and I received the 502 error.

(I don't know if this is the reason, but I installed some code listed here: https://blog.quantinsti.com/install-ta-lib-python/
**twice.** Why ? I didn't even need to do it, I'm just an idiot. It stopped working **almost immediately** after I did this)

This is my error log when i enter the command : sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2021/05/26 00:30:53 [error] 487#487: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, clien(base(ba((b((bas(ba(ba((ba((b(b(((b((b(b((b(((b(((((((((((((((((base) (base) u(ba(base(base) ubu(
```

Otherwise, could it be that my memory usage is at 99.8%? Just thinking of potential problems.

Any help would be supremely appreciated.

Edit: Below is my sites available (/etc/nginx/sites-available/jupyter_app.conf):

```
server {
    server_name jupyter_notebook;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }
}
```

Comment: The lines are from an 20 hrs. timeframe. Which are relevant to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

Is your upstream application running and accepting connections?

Check in your machine whether the below service and port is up and listening for connections, if not start that upstream service:

```
http://localhost:8888;
```

To check open port status, run the below command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: I can't run that command because I don't have netstat installed, and it says no space left on device to download xD

Comment: Check what is consuming the disk space - clean up some space and start the service. Remove downloaded files, /tmp data, etc

Comment: Package 'net-tools'  has no installation candidate.

Comment: ahhhhh it works now after deleting all the useless files. Awesome thanks a lot

Comment: Glad worked!, if it solves your issues, mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the connection settings to upstream is correct.

Also you can check the memory usage by using:

```
df -h
```

And this will show you the disk space if the disk space is full try to delete the log files or irrelevant files and check if the site works.

Comment: hey so I checked my memory usage, and it is being 100% used by /dev/root. I don't know anything else, or how to look into whether some files are irrelevant. Any ideas?

Comment: You can check for folder size in your root directory to identify which folder has maximum size by using 
    sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /root_folder or refer to link https://linuxize.com/post/how-get-size-of-file-directory-linux/